# why if I insert 1,2,2 as input the result will be 0 instead of one

Tags: c++

```
cin >> a >> b >> n; 
int ans=0; 
c=max(a,b);
d=min(a,b);
while(n>c)
    if(d+c>n) {
    ans++;
    break;
}
cout << ans;
}
```

why if I insert 1,2,2 as input the result will be 0 instead of one

Comment: Where are the variables declared?  What are their types?

Comment: Hmm I do not see how it could be that `n>c` and `n<c+d` at the same time for positive numbers. And you do not change neither `n` or `c` so if you are in the loop you will be always in it - ie you would have endless loop. So your code does not make any sense for your data. It could only work for some negative numbers but loop is meaningless even in that case.

Comment: And on top of that your code is not compilable - brackets are unbalanced. So without [mcve] your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

If you had a debugger that you could step through the code with, the mistake would have been easy to find.

When you get to the while loop, `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `n = 2`, `c = 2`, `d = 1` and `ans = 0`.
Since the condition `n > c` is false (because `!(2 > 2)`) the body does not get executed and you get what you started with.